# Animator based Animation does not work on Android 2.3

Tags: android, animation, android-2.3-gingerbread

My app developed based on Android 4.0 APIs, it works good. Now I have to support devices of Android 2.3, some Animator related features failed to work.

I know Animator is released from 3.0. My question is how can I work around that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [THIS LIB](http://nineoldandroids.com/)

it adds the Animator to old devices.